# how to change xml attibute using xslt

Tags: xslt

i have xml attribute dsc:

```
<DMD dsc="1">
```

In schema

```
<xs:attribute name="dsc" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
```

I want to change value "0" to "no" and "1" to "yes".

My xslt:

```
<td style="padding-left:10px; width:1.64in; ">
            <xsl:for-each select="@dsc">
                <span style="color:#0024c0; ">
                   <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>                                                               
               </span>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
```

I tried xsl:template match and xsl:choose but i still dont have a solution. I can transform elements, but no attribute. Thanks

Comment: You provided too few code for a [mcve]. So people trying to answer gonna have to speculate what you really expect to be a worthy answer. Without further info answers will be based on a certain amount of guessing.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following stylesheet which uses *templates* to replace all occurrences of the `dsc` attribute with the appropriate values:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <!-- identity template - copy all (other) nodes as given -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Replace '1' attribute values with 'yes' values -->
  <xsl:template match="@dsc[.='1']">
    <xsl:attribute name="dsc">
        <xsl:value-of select="'yes'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Replace '0' attribute values with 'no' values -->
  <xsl:template match="@dsc[.='0']">
    <xsl:attribute name="dsc">
        <xsl:value-of select="'no'"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: My xslt has a template before <html> tag: <xsl:template match="/"> I added Your code after </xsl:template> on the end of the xslt but now xslt dont convert value, but "0" or "1" just disappeared from visualization. The field is empty.

Comment: The order of the templates doesn't matter in XSLT, What matters is what templates are executed. Try adding `<apply-templates />` to you <html> template. Or show a bigger part of the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath `@dsc` is correct if you are in the context of the element `DMD`, but this is not visible due to the partial XSL you posted.

If you are not in the context of `DMD`, the xpath is `whatever/elements/DMD/@dsc`.

However, the short-form `.` is for the current element. You cannot use that to get the value of an attribute as far as I know.

And I don't see why you do a loop with `xsl:for-each`. There is only one attribute `dsc`.

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
 <td style="padding-left:10px; width:1.64in; ">
        <xsl:for-each select="//@dsc">
            <span style="color:#0024c0; ">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="//@dsc='1'"><xsl:text>yes</xsl:text></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>no</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
           </span>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </td>
```

Comment: it works but element DMD has maxOccurs unbonded <xs:element name="DMD" type="DMDType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> . When I have one element it ok, finally i have "yes" when attribute is "1". But when I have more than one element DMD all of attribute are "yes" despite some of them has a value "0"